Position of never with infinitive
why in a sentence "She is often said never to have revised the material" do we place never before to have, not after to have?

Either is fine, so the premise of this question is faulty.

English generally favours placing adverbs like "never" closer to the verbs they modify without breaking up the main verb phrase.
So it would be much more likely for a native English speaker to say either:

"It is often said that she never revised the material."
"She is often said to have never revised the material."

Some could argue that it doesn't matter, but comprehension is particularly important here because you're using two different adverbs of time ("often" and "never") which mean very different things so it needs to be very clear which they modify. It's often said that she never revised.
